# How do I copy a formula field to text

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to do a simple copy from a formula field to a text field on the same object. Problem is, it doesn't seem to be copying, and I still see the old value. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
trigger Copy on OBJECT__c (after insert) {
       List<OBJECT__c> obj = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM OBJECT__c WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
     for (OBJECT__c o: obj) {

                   string s = o.Status__c; //copy the notes to a string object
                   o.Cycle_Status__c = s;  
      }
               update obj; 
}
```

Update: I think the problem stems from the fact that I'm trying to get text from a formula field.

Comment: If you put a `system.debug(s);` line in your for loop, what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done without code.

Create a workflow rule with a corresponding field update.  Set it to run when the record is created and every time it is edited.  Set the criteria to fire on ischanged(your formula field).  Create the second text field, and in the workflow field update, set the text field as the destination field, and the value of the formula field as the source field.

Answer (score 1):

I expect you're getting an error since you're updating a field but not including it in your query. Add `Cycle_Status__c` to the SOQL query and give it another try. Other than that it looks correct.

Comment: Nah. It's still doing it, I added Cycle_Status__c to the query. I suspect it's because i'm trying to grab a value from a formula field. It's something to do with that formula field not updating. Not sure why though

Comment: What field type is Cycle_Status__c ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your trigger to before insert, not after insert.